# Node Js EventEmitter is not listening events calling from another class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried to pass an event from a class to another function, the emit event is not passing to that function.

App.js

```
const Logger = require('./logger');
const logger = new Logger();
logger.on('msgLoged', (arg) => {
   console.log("6. Listner called !!!", arg);
});
```

logger.js

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class Logger extends EventEmitter {
   log(message) {
       console.log(message);
       this.emit('msgLoged', {id: 1, data: "someathing"})
    }
}
```

Comment: You never `log` something to your `logger`, right? You just add the listener but you never invoke `logger.log`

Comment: ok, thanks. Now it's running

Answer (score 0):

The event will get triggered/emitted when you call the log function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).